# How do one enable MFA delete on S3 bucket for non-root user?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I've enabled MFA delete for root user. But if I want to give such rights to certain non-root user as well. I've configured aws using root credentials and using the following command to enable mfa delete on root:

aws s3api put-bucket-versioning --bucket  --versioning-configuration Status=Enabled,MFADelete=Enabled --mfa " "

For non-root user, I'm using arn of user to which I want to give access and mfa-code for the same. However, aws is throwing following error:
**An error occurred (InvalidAccessKeyId) when calling the DeleteObject operation: The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records**

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, only the **bucket owner** (i.e., **root** account) can enable MFA Delete on a S3 bucket. And this can only be done via awscli and not via AWS console.

**Reference:** https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/Versioning.html#MultiFactorAuthenticationDelete